# How to reduce external API calls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have integrated facebook, twitter API's in my rails application for getting hashtag records. Everything is working fine but API calls are taking too long too execute which is really very frustrating. I googled around to get rid of this. There are curl_multi functions available in PHP. Is there something available in rails too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the PHP thing, but if you want to asynchronously process API calls use a queue. Rails provides us with the ActiveJob facade that allows us to use a variety of queues on the back-end. A good tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/delay-api-calls-to-twilio-with-rails-active-job-and-sidekiq.html).